# how to secure data in sharepoint custom list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, encryption, custom-lists

I have stored database connection string in a column of SharePoint custom list.
Through c# code i used to fetch the value from that column and my application gets connected to specified database. But that connection string is visible to everyone having access to the list. How we can encrypt that value so that it cannot be visible to everyone but my application can be connected to the database with minimum or no change in code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [Secure Store Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557754%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for encrypted credential storage. See [this tutorial](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.cz/2010/12/using-sharepoint-2010-secure-store.html).

Comment: but if i use Secure Store Service then i need to make changes in the code. I am looking for the solution where i need not have to change code

Comment: Instead if i able to create new column which stores my connection string and display the encrypted text that will also work. I need help how to create that custom column field of type Encrypted text

Comment: I'm not aware of non-code solution for obfuscating column display. Why don't you break permission inheritance and limit access to the list only to your application?

Comment: although i limit permission but still the data in list column will be visible to developer. Is there any method to create encrypted column in list?

Comment: You could create event receiver which would encrypt the field value before saving. But your application would have to decrypt it before using. Or you could create custom field type. But beware that the correct solution would be using Secure Store Service as I stated before.

Comment: yes Secure Store Service is the correct solution but for previously developed applications its difficult to make changes in code as the number of applications are more